# "The login is invalid " issue with cPanel

Tags: php, linux, ssh, cpanel, openssh

The credentials are correct and it's working fine on another PC, but not mine. I don't know what the problem is.

I am getting the following message,

[image]

I can access the website and I can log in to the back-office, but not the server -- I've tried using SSH, FTP, cPanel, and WHM.

This is what I get when trying with SSH.

```
[hardik@ShriKrishna ~]$ ssh -v eimimo.com -l username
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0j-fips 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 50: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to eimimo.com [50.115.112.203] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/hardik/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/hardik/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hardik/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hardik/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA d6:e2:81:e9:a1:7e:4a:98:2b:7e:88:ac:a9:1e:78:73
debug1: Host 'eimimo.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/hardik/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/hardik/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/hardik/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
eimimo@eimimo.com's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
eimimo@eimimo.com's password:
```

So, what is the issue? Why can I not log into the server?
.

Comment: And you're *certain* you're entering the correct password?

Comment: @MichaelRushton absolutely sure, because its working in my friends PC.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the server faces security issues and suggests to some/all users to use the secure authentication login.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION 1

May be your Local internet service provider ip blocked in server firewall,

Visit the below URL and get your local isp ip address,

http://www.whatismyip.com/

Login into your SSH and use the below cmd

csf -a ipaddress
SOLUTION 2:

It is your local pc or browser issue,

May be your server ip address blocked in your local pc antivirus or firewall.
SOLUTION 3:

Contact your hosting service provider along with your local isp ip address,

Ask them to remove the ip address from your server firewall.